# How to fill checkboxes by ajax request to function RelatedUserAccessPermission on razor page mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I work on .NET core 7 MVC razor page . I face issue I can't fill check boxes Id `StockTake` and `ShelfLabelPrint` by using ajax request to this function `RelatedUserAccessPermission`

URL below I run it on browser to access function `RelatedUserAccessPermission`

```
https://localhost:7160/AddUserAccess?handler=RelatedUserAccessPermission

 public JsonResult OnGetRelatedUserAccessPermission(int UserId)
        {

            var UserAccess = _db.UserAccess.ToList();
            return new JsonResult(UserAccess);

        }
```

Data Returned from function `OnGetRelatedUserAccessPermission`

```
ModuleCode AccessRight UserId
1           1           1220
2           1           1220
```

so Based on user id

```
    if(modulecode=1 and accessright=1)
    
    then StockTake checkbox will be checked based on value =1
    
    if(modulecode=2 and accessright=1)
    
    then ShelfLabelPrint checkbox will be checked  based on value =2
    if(modulecode=3 and accessright=1)
    
    then Transfer checkbox will be checked based on value =3
```

on AddUserAccess.cshtml

```
<button id="FillCheckBox" type="submit" class="col-sm-1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="user-id" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label" style="font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">User ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input id="useraccess-id" asp-for="UserAccess.UserId" type="text" class="form-control" style=" margin-left:10px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <input id="StockTake" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="1">
        <label for="lblStockTake">Stock Take</label>

        <input id="ShelfLabelPrint" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="2">
        <label for="lblShelfLabel">Shelf Label Print</label>

        <input id="Transfer" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="3">
        <label for="lblTransfer" style="margin-right:5px;">Transfer</label>
```

for more details what I expect

[image: How to fill checkboxes on razor Page]

**Exactly logic I need to Implement by ajax request**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#FillCheckBox').click(function () { 
                    //How to Make Ajax Request Fill CheckBoxes
if(modulecode=1 and accessright=1)
    
    then StockTake checkbox will be checked
    
    if(modulecode=2 and accessright=1)
    
    then ShelfLabelPrint checkbox will be checked 
    if(modulecode=3 and accessright=1)
    
    then Transfer checkbox will be checked


                    
                
            });
            });
        </script>
```

**updated answer**

```
<form method="post">
<button id="FillCheckBox" type="submit" class="col-sm-1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="user-id" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label" style="font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">User ID</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input id="useraccess-id" asp-for="UserAccess.UserId" type="text" class="form-control" style=" margin-left:10px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;" />
</div>
        </div>
        <input id="StockTake" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="1">
        <label for="lblStockTake">Stock Take</label>
<input id="StockTake" type="hidden"  value="false" />
        <input id="ShelfLabelPrint" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="2">
        <label for="lblShelfLabel">Shelf Label Print</label>

        <input id="Transfer" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="3">
        <label for="lblTransfer" style="margin-right:5px;">Transfer</label>

        
       
        
    </form>
```

this is full code to my razor html form

if I leave method=post then it not working filling check boxes

if I remove method=post it working success and fill check box ajax
working
so whay this happen

Comment: can you please check modifications

Comment: "if I remove method=post it working success and fill check box ajax working so whay this happen" you  can use `F12` to see there is error message in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For test, I change the checkbox `asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE"` into `asp-for="UserAccess.ck"` because there is `ModuleCode` property.

> Exactly logic I need to Implement by ajax request

I have a work demo, you can refer to it, hope it can helps.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#FillCheckBox').click(function () {
            var id = $("#useraccess-id").val();     
            alert(id);
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/AddUserAccess?Handler=RelatedUserAccessPermission",
                data: { UserId: id },
                success: function (result) {
                    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
                    {         
                        if(result[i].moduleCode == 1 & result[i].accessRight == 1)
                        { $("#StockTake").prop("checked", true); };
                        if (result[i].moduleCode == 2 & result[i].accessRight == 1)
                        { $("#ShelfLabelPrint").prop("checked", true); };
                        if (result[i].moduleCode == 3 & result[i].accessRight == 1) 
                        { $("#Transfer").prop("checked", true); };                      
                    };
               },
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
                });
                });
</script>
```

result:
[image]

**Update**

> if I remove method=post it working success and fill check box ajax
> working so whay this happen

You are getting a 400 (Bad Request) response because the framework expects the RequestVerificationToken as part of the posted request.The framework uses this to prevent possible CSRF attacks. If your request does not have this information, the framework will return the 400 bad request.  To make post work, please do some change as below:

1.Change the post method like:

```
 public JsonResult OnPostRelatedUserAccessPermission(int UserId)
        {..}
```

2.In the cshtml, add

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<form method="post">
...
```

3.The Ajax request should send the anti-forgery token in request header to the server.

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
         $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
 },
```

4.In Program.cs, since the script sends the token in a header called XSRF-TOKEN, configure the antiforgery service to look for the XSRF-TOKEN header:

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

5.Because use form with submit, but use ajax post userId, add `event.preventDefault();` to avoid submit with null useId. Full code like:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#FillCheckBox').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var id = $("#useraccess-id").val();
                alert(id);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/AddUserAccess?Handler=RelatedUserAccessPermission",
                    data: { UserId: id },
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            if (result[i].moduleCode == 1 & result[i].accessRight == 1) { $("#StockTake").prop("checked", true); };
                            if (result[i].moduleCode == 2 & result[i].accessRight == 1) { $("#ShelfLabelPrint").prop("checked", true); };
                            if (result[i].moduleCode == 3 & result[i].accessRight == 1) { $("#Transfer").prop("checked", true); };
                        };
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but after apply code it success apply but after than less 1 second it unchecked again so i invistigate to issue i found method post make this issue so how to solve it please

Comment: @ahmed abdelaziz  what do you mean    "but after than less 1 second it unchecked again" ? My demo like https://i.stack.imgur.com/37cOC.gif  won't 1 second it unchecked .

Comment: what i need code working but after one second it changed to unchecked so why this happen and how to solve this isseue please

Comment: @ahmed abdelaziz  based your provided code I cannot reproduce  after one second it changed to unchecked . Could you create a small demo and share it via gihub ?

Comment: i updated my answer on original post can you please check last update

Comment: @ahmed abdelaziz  You mean you want  to use post method? But your OnGetRelatedUserAccessPermission is get method ,do you want to change it to OnPostRelatedUserAccessPermission ?

Comment: this web page will insert and update changes for check box so i make it post

Comment: @ahmed abdelaziz ok, I will change my answer to make the post method work .

Comment: @ahmed abdelaziz Could  you have a look at my update.